# How to use TimeSeriesForecasting in KnowledgeFlow?

Tags: weka

Weka Explorer provides Time Series Forecasting perspective and it is easy to use.

However, what should I do, if I want to use KnowledgeFlow for time series forecast?

what if I want to save original dataset with predictions?

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions** (Thanks to the help from people from WekaList, especially, Mark Hall, Eibe Frank)

1. Open knowledgeFlow, load dataset with ArffLoader
2. go to setting, check time series forecasting perspective, right-click ArffLoader to send to all perspective
3. go to time series forecasting perspective to set up a model
4. run the model and copy the model to clipboard
5. ctrl + v, and click to paste model to Data mining process canvas
6. save prediction along with original data with ArffSaver